postgres sql: calculate start and end dates in date sequence
I've requirement to process only year worth of data from source.
If data in source is over a year, then I need to split date values for data to be picked up in next turn for extract.
Imagine two date values: start and end dates.
start_date: '2019-06-25' 
end_date: '2024-10-15' 

Difference between given values end date and start date: it is 1939 days.
Context:
I mention here start and end dates only because these values are derived after my calculation (which is already done in the beginning separately).
I just don't know how to split the whole start and end date values in 365 days, which will give me time period of maximum 365 days. This is where I need your help. Desired output provided below.
Once you share how to split, I can use the code and provide each of these start end date values via loop to run extract only for that period.
I don't need help with this piece.
select date '2024-10-15' -  date '2019-06-25' 
Result> 1939  (in days)

Based on the start and end dates, how can I get the sequence of date output in the following format in a way that each period is no more than 365 days. first start date value will be '2019-06-25' and last will be '2024-10-15' s it was the end_dt value.
Desired output in sequence: 
start_dt      end_dt
---------------------------------
'2019-06-25'|'2020-06-24'
'2020-06-25'|'2021-06-25'
'2021-06-26'|'2022-06-26'
'2022-06-27'|'2023-06-27'
'2023-06-28'|'2024-10-15' 

Calculation should be dynamic to work for any date value in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. For instance, If start_dt: '2019-06-25' and end_dt: '2020-10-25' there will only be two rows since first value is over 365 and second value is less than 365.
Desired output: 
start_dt      end_dt
---------------------------------
'2019-06-25'|'2020-06-24'
'2020-06-25'|'2020-10-25'

For instance, lets do the calculation without checking if difference is over 365 days. This would remove complexity for anyone who is trying to help.
This way, If difference is over 365 automatically we could have few rows of output (as desired output above), If not then we will only have only one row (please see below):
Desired output: 
start_dt      end_dt
---------------------------------
'2019-06-25'|'2019-10-25'

explored LAG function but did not meet the requirement

Your  options have problems for  two reasons: 1) '2019-06-25'|'2020-06-24' != '2019-06-25'|'2019-12-31' so you are going to get totally different answers. 2) In the second option '2019-06-25'|'2019-12-31' is not covering the same range as '2020-01-01'|'2020-12-31'. and does not  meet your requirement ...where all the full year starting in Jan and ending in Dec.  You need to describe in more detail what is you are trying to achieve?

Sorry, my bad, I agree, thanks for sharing.  Please keep option 1 for solution, and I've since removed option 2, which was ending with YYYY-12-31 as it is more than 365 days.

For the grouped by year version, it is quite simple:
SELECT MIN(g.dt)::date AS start_dt, MAX(g.dt)::date AS end_dt
FROM generate_series(date '2019-06-25', '2024-10-15', '1 day') g(dt)
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM g.dt)
ORDER BY MIN(g.dt)::date;

results in
  start_dt  |   end_dt
------------+------------
 2019-06-25 | 2019-12-31
 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-31
 2021-01-01 | 2021-12-31
 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31
 2023-01-01 | 2023-12-31
 2024-01-01 | 2024-10-15

To get one year periods starting at the start date:
WITH RECURSIVE year AS (
    SELECT
        g.dt::date AS start_dt,
        LEAST((g.dt::date + interval '1 year')::date - 1, '2024-10-15') AS end_dt
    FROM generate_series(date '2019-06-25', '2024-10-15', '1 day') g(dt)
), relevant_year(start_dt, end_dt) AS (
    SELECT y.start_dt, y.end_dt
    FROM year y
    WHERE y.start_dt = '2019-06-25'

    UNION

    SELECT y.start_dt, y.end_dt
    FROM year y
    INNER JOIN relevant_year ry ON ry.end_dt + 1 = y.start_dt
)
SELECT ry.start_dt, ry.end_dt
FROM relevant_year ry
ORDER BY ry.start_dt;

returns
  start_dt  |   end_dt
------------+------------
 2019-06-25 | 2020-06-24
 2020-06-25 | 2021-06-24
 2021-06-25 | 2022-06-24
 2022-06-25 | 2023-06-24
 2023-06-25 | 2024-06-24
 2024-06-25 | 2024-10-15

You may adjust this yourself to your exact definition of a year and handling of leapdays.

@zaino22 Did this solve your problem? If yes, please accept the answer. Otherwise, please let me know what is missing.

awesome, thank you so much for sharing both option, you resolved my issue. Appreciate your timely help!
